# How to connect a bluetooth device by SPP

Tags: iphone, bluetooth, mfi

How to connect a bluetooth device by Serial Port Profile in iPhone using Objective C? I have a Bar Code Scanner and i want to read bar code into my app.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot - unless the barcode is an [Apple MFi Bluetooth accessory](http://developer.apple.com/programs/mfi/) .

Comment: thanks Dennis, can you tell me approach to implement Bar Code Scanner functionality. I have to implement same functionality shown here http://support.shopkeep.com/entries/20634331-setting-up-your-ipad-register-for-barcode-scanning